# About STARTTLS SMTP Command

Tags: ssl, .net-4.0, tcp, sslstream, starttls

Is STARTTLS command exclusive for TLS channels or can it be used with SSL channels ?
Is there any TlsStream which can be used , as SslStream since .Net4 does not support TLS even if it is available as member of the SslProtocols enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

STARTTLS tells the server to start SSL/TLS handshake and can be used with all versions of SSL/TLS. But the server might require that the client supports certain versions (i.e. older versions of SSL can be disabled on the server). In this case the handshake won't be completed.

Comment: I just found out that .Net4.5 seems to support tls 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2, but platform supprt is actually limited to windows 7 and 8 , i guess..Is there any open source .Net tools for ssl / tls ?